# node.js - index.js to share mysql details - with page.js?

Tags: node.js

index.js already has mysql connection details
page.js to be able to use these details
so that i do not have to provide mysql details
to page.js again.

also.. page.js 's output needs to be made
available to index.js so index.js can see the
mysql query results.

index.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '-------------',
    user     : '-----',
    password : '-------',
    database : '-----',
});

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    require('page.js);
    res.end('test');
}).listen(80);
```

page.js:

```
connection.connect();

var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM t1 order by id desc limit 5';

connection.query(queryString, function(err,res,fields){
bb = JSON.stringify(res);
});

connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `page.js`:

```
exports.makeQuery = function(connection, callback) {
  connection.connect();

  var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM t1 order by id desc limit 5';

  connection.query(queryString, function(err,res,fields){
    connection.end();
    if (err) {return callback(err)};

    bb = JSON.stringify(res);
    callback(null, bb);
  });
}
```

In other:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var page = require('page.js');   //note here
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '-------------',
    user     : '-----',
    password : '-------',
    database : '-----',
});

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    page.makeQuery(connection, function(err, result){
      if(err) return res.end(err);
      res.end(result);
    });
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: Although i chose this answer as valid.. it turns out connection.end(); can cause a problem 2nd time around because it goes in a que in mysql.  i moved connection.connect(); to the main.js and completely eliminated connection.end(); until further data.  ( perhaps connection.connect(); also goes in a que in mysql but going in a que ( being exected ) only once might be the solution ?)

Answer (score 0):

If page.js should act like a function (input & output), then by all means, make it so:

**page.js**

```
module.exports = function(connection, callback){
  connection.connect();

  var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM t1 order by id desc limit 5';
  var bb = undefined

  connection.query(queryString, function(err,res,fields){
    callback(JSON.stringify(res))
    connection.end();
  });
}
```

**index.js**

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  require('./page')(connection, function(result){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    doSomethingWith(result); //result is bb
    res.end('test');
  });
}).listen(80);
```